# Google Sign-In of API Google Play services 8.3

Tags: android, google-play-services

the new Sign-In API is released by [Play-Services 8.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/11/whats-new-in-google-play-services-83.html)

I have 2 questions:

1. Does new API need switching on like former Google+ API in the Google Developer Console? I can see Google+ still now instead Google SignIn.
2. When I use new SignIn API, is the ID the same one I get by using old Google+ API?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gonna it, I have updated a lot my Apps that use G+ Login, it seems that the new SignIn takes over G+ Login directly. So this question can be closed.

Comment: You should accept your own answer then, especially if you can provide any reference or additional information.